# How to use java on client-side code of Worklight?

Tags: java, javascript, client-side, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm working with a `worklight` project (Hybrid application),
Currently i'm calling `server-side adapter` with `JavaScript` and handling fetched data with `JavaScript` and having many problem of parsing data.
Can anybody help me to use `JAVA` at `client-side` programming(Anyhow if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Java for client side programming. If you're creating an Android application, then of course you can implement whatever you want in java and then use cordova to pass your data down, but it doesn't look like thats what you want to do.

I would take a different approach though. You say you're using a server side adapter, and adapters **can** use custom Java code. You should use your server side adapter to get your data from the backend, then add your custom java code and parse the data in the adapter. Once your data is parsed and in a consumable format, then you can pass the data from the adapter to the client.

[Here is the documentation](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_08_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf) for using java in an adapter.

Answer (score 1):

In Worklight you can develop by using different APIs:
JavaScript client-side API for hybrid apps
Objective-C client-side API for native iOS apps
Java™ client-side API for native Android apps
Java client-side API for Java Platform, Micro Edition (Java ME) apps
You can also use your own custom libraries or third-party libraries when you create mobile applications in Worklight Studio.

src: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_creating_client_side_of_app.html

More information about Java client-side programming:

- Java™ client-side API for native Android apps
  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fc_java_api_native_and_apps.html
- Java client-side API for Java Platform, Micro Edition (Java ME) apps
  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fc_java_me_api.html

Comment: But we are developing a hybrid application and for that i didn't find any java handler, that's why I'm here

Comment: If you want to build hybrid applications, you will have to do it with javascript. If you want to fetch data from the adapters in Java, you narrow your hybrid app to Android or Java ME apps. If you want to fetch data from the adapters from most devices, you will have to use Javascript. Because Javascript is supported on most devices.

Maybe post your problem of parsing data in javascript, so we can help you with that?